# Duplicate Symbol when including header only library more than once

Tags: c

I made a simple helper library for a little game I'm making. In such library I have some core functions that must perform as fast as possible since they're called thousands of times per game frame.

If I declare them "inline" and split their declaration (`library.h`) from their implementation (`library.c`) and include them in the game file (`game.c`), I guess they're not inlined / optimized since declaring them directly in `game.c` and compiling the game with `gcc -O3` gives me a performance boost of more that 60 times.

To solve this issue, I decided to make my library a header-only library. I have all my framework constants, vars and functions in `library.h`. Including it in `game.c` still gives me the maximum performance.

Now, the problem is that whenever I include `library.h` in more than one file (say `game1.c` and `game2.c`) I get a long list of `duplicate symbol` errors when compiling the game. The library has `#pragma once` but still the problem occurs.

How to actually write header-only libraries or make sure that an inline function from an external library is actually optimized?

Thanks

Comment: Do you *define* variables or functions in your header file?

Comment: You only want to declare the variables in header and have a seperate `.c` file for definitions

Comment: You want to declare the functions `static`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As alk already commented, you need to declare the functions and global variables in the header file `static`.

The `static` keyword means the object (function or variable) has *internal linkage*; that it is only visible in the current compilation unit, and it will not be included in any symbol tables.

It is also a good idea to use include guards, so that if you have another header file that includes your header, and the C source file includes both your header file and that other header file, your header file only gets included once. (The lines with `FOOLIB_H` comprise the include guard in the below example.)

Consider the following trivial fixed-size stack example, **foolib.h**:

```
#ifndef   FOOLIB_H
#define   FOOLIB_H

#include <stdlib.h>

#define   STACK_MAX  256

static size_t  stack_size = 0;
static double  stack_item[STACK_MAX];

static inline int  stack_push(const double  item)
{
    if (stack_size < STACK_MAX) {
        stack_item[stack_size++] = item;
        return 0;
    } else
        return -1;
}

static inline double  stack_pop(const double  empty)
{
    if (stack_size > 0)
        return stack_item[--stack_size];
    else
        return empty;
}

#endif /* FOOLIB_H */
```

Each compilation unit (each source file you compile separately) that includes the above (`#include "foolib.h"`), gets their own local private stack they can use via `stack_push()` and `stack_pop()`.

The reason for marking the functions `static inline` rather than just `static` is that the former tells the compiler that it is okay to omit the function altogether, if it is not used. In particular, if you compile code with `gcc -Wall`, gcc warns if a `static` function is not used, but does not warn if a `static inline` function is not used. Other than that, there is not much practical difference.